# Why are there different types of transaction manager?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, transactions, spring-transactions, jta

I am confused about different types of transaction manager in a web application:

**Spring transaction manger vs JPA transaction manager vs Hibernate transaction manager vs JTA transaction manger vs database transaction manager**

I did some googling about the above transaction managers but am still not clear.

For example:

`Hibernate tx manager` uses `Database tx manager`

`JPA tx manager` uses `Hibernate tx`
 manager

`Spring tx manager` uses `JPA transaction manager` or `JTA tx manager`

Edited:
 Configuration Example from my application is below:
samaple

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
```

so if I consider above example does JPA transaction manger uses hibernate transaction manager and in turn hibernate manger uses JTA manager am I corrrect?

Does this mean every transaction manager uses an underlying transaction manager?

Comment: What is your question? You can simply check the type hierarchy and the implementations.

Comment: I would like to know how they are interrelated with each other?does every transaction manger works with underlying manger or they work independently.

Comment: So you want to know the implementation details of each transaction manager. Why don't you just check out the implementations then?

Comment: not implementation just concept,for example does Hibernate tx manager uses Database tx manager

JPA tx manager uses Hibernate tx manager

Spring tx manager uses JPA transaction manager or JTA tx manager is my understanding is correct

Answer (score 0):

When you say "every transaction manager uses and underlying transaction manager" you are not exactly correct.

Taking Spring for example, a transaction strategy is defined by the `PlatformTransactionManager` interface. It is not tied to a lookup strategy such as JNDI. `PlatformTransactionManager` implementations are defined like any other object (or bean) in the Spring Framework IoC container. This benefit alone makes Spring Framework transactions a worthwhile abstraction even when you work with JTA. Transactional code can be tested much more easily than if it used JTA directly.

So Spring offers multiple implementation possibilities with regard to database transaction management.

Comment: but there is one configuration in my application which confuses me.my application spring+jpa+hibernate,its pretty old project.they have used JPA as transaction manager and in JTA in JPA hibernate config below is the

Comment: samaple <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  <property name="jpaDialect">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
  </property>
 </bean>   and <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform</prop>
    <prop key="transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
    <prop key="current_session_context_class">jta</prop>

Comment: so if I consider above example does JPA transaction manger uses hibernate transaction manager and in turn hibernate manger uses JTA manager am I corrrect?